# Javascript function access

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a block of code in `$(function() { function parseData(){...} )};`

I also have a function declared outside of the ready block.  This is outside since I hook it up in codebehind ie `ddlCategories.Attributes.Add("onchange", "getDataFields()");`

From the getDataFields function, I need to call parseData but it does not seem to find it.

How do I access my parseData() which is in my ready block, from outside of the ready block?

(sorry if some of terminology is off - I am now to JS)

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any reason parseData() has to be in the ready block? Why not just make it a top level function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function parseData() { ... }

$(document).ready( function() {
   ddl.Categories.....
}
<script>
```

Comment: Well, then I will have the same issue elsewhere, since other things call parseData().

Comment: Yes, but what's parseData doing? Unless it's doing dom manipulations, then there's no reason it can't be a top level functionality, which makes it available to all your scripts, regardless of where/when they execute.

Comment: I just tried this.  I have a bunch of variables that are defined inside the ready block so that makes it difficult.  Is there no way to call into a function in the ready block?

Comment: global variables aren't a good idea. but if you need them, then put their original definition outside the block, then set their values in the ready block.

Answer (score 1):

Just define it outside your ready block. It's currently inaccessible due to the scope of the function.

Definitions can always safely go outside `$(function() { ... })` blocks because nothing is executed.

```
$(function() { ... });

function parseData() { ... }
```

However, you seem to have a syntax error: `)};` should be `});`.

Comment: The syntax was because I was typing off the cuff.

Comment: @Jeff: If you would like to access functions everywhere, you should expose them directly instead of inside `$(...)` blocks. Otherwise, those functions would not be accessible outside the `$(...)`. This behaviour is called 'scope'.

Answer (score 1):

Declare your parseData function outside of the self-executing $(function(){}); block.

```
var parseData = function () { ... };

$(function() { ... });
```

If there are things you need to reference inside the self-executing function, then declare the function globally but define it inside the self-executing function:

```
var parseData;

$(function() { parseData = function () { ... }; });
```

As an aside, declaring functions or variables globally is a bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

You should declare the function outside the `$(function() { ... })` callback.

Comment: Sorry but I do not understand